# Bootstrap: How to add top level nav button as a child for mobile version

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

I have been working on making a more responsive theme for a wordpress site using bootstrap. I setup the main nav to expand child items `onhover` instead of a click event. This is the [plugin I am using](http://cameronspear.com/demos/twitter-bootstrap-hover-dropdown/) to accomplish that. That works great on both mobile & desktop. I understand & have read the developers reasoning for designing it to require a click event, but I was hoping to keep the hover functionality.

My one remaining issue is the top level nav is also a page, and not clickable on mobile. On a mobile device, it expands & collapses properly when you click on the top level nav, but I can't click the top item. So what I would like to do is if the screen resolution is small enough to be a tablet or smart phone, include the top item as a child as well, so it's clickable.

So if your example nav item was like this on desktop

```
CLASSES
- HISTORY
- MATH
```

On smaller resolutions like a tablet/phone it would look like:

```
CLASSES
- CLASSES
- HISTORY
- MATH
```

How could I accomplish this, or what's the best alternative? Here is what my nav currently looks like in Wordpress:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="brand" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a>
        <div class="nav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
                <?php
                if ( function_exists('wp_nav_menu') ) {
                    wp_nav_menu( array(
                            'menu'       => 'top_menu',
                            'depth'      => 2,
                            'container'  => false,
                            'menu_class' => 'nav',
                            'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu',
                            //Process nav menu using our custom nav walker
                            'walker' => new twitter_bootstrap_nav_walker())
                    );
                }
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

`twitter_bootstrap_nav_walker` extends Wordpress's `Walker_Nav_Menu` class. It adds the proper attributes to pages loaded from the DB needed by bootstrap.

Here's what the HTML looks like on a nav item with children. The `data-hover="dropdown"` is what makes the tree auto-expand on mouse over.

```
<a href="http://localhost/classes" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-target="#" class="dropdown-toggle js-activated">CLASSES <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using bootstrap, a quick and dirty solution could be to simply use the [Responsive Utility classes](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive). You can set the "CLASSES" menu item to have `.visible-phone` and `.visible-tablet` classes